# Removing last Azure app service also removes parent plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Here is my simplified Azure architecture:

- ResourceGroup1 => AppServicePlan
- ResourceGroup2 -> AppService1, AppService2

Once this architecture is in place, I remove the apps one by one. When i delete (tried in portal and with PowerShell as well) the last app, the plan gets also deleted...

Is it by design or a bug ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is by design. The reason it was done that way is to avoid continuing to charge for an unused Plan, which would take some customers by surprise if they don't fully grasp the distinction between Plan and Web App.

So the only time a Plan can be empty is right after it's created. After that, any transition from 1 to 0 contained Web Apps triggers the deletion of the Plan.

If you want to avoid this behavior, the simplest workaround is to include a 'dummy' Web App in the Plan to keep it alive. You can stop that Web App, so it doesn't consume any resources on the VMs.

Comment: Thanks David. The dummy web app is an (ugly) option but it looks like i don't have the choice. I will also look for resource locks. I could setup a CannotDelete lock with the provisioning principal, preventing the de-provisioning principal to delete it. What do you think ?

Comment: I doubt that would work. That's because the deletion is happening from the 'inside', whereas your lock will only prevent an explicit deletion going through the ARM API.

Comment: I see. Ok let's go for a dummy app. I think that this behavior should be an option when creating a plan. Actually, my plan acts as a pool for Web Apps, and it can sometimes no longer host any ones.

Comment: Yes, it would be a valid feature for it to be configurable. Best place to suggest it is https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-sites/.

Comment: As an aside, the current behavior is document [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/#app-service-plan-cleanup) in the 'App Service Plan cleanup' section.

Comment: Thanks David, i just posted my idea :-)

Comment: Posting the link here so others who find this SO question can locate/upvote it: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/16684741-automatic-deletion-of-app-service-plan-should-be-a

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you can use this parameter --keep-empty-plan

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-delete-examples